# How to override display: table cell

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

I am having an issue with the layout of my website in Firefox it works in Chrome. It is also hard to show you my code because I am using some plug ins to add elements so it is not just in normal HTML. The images inside the table cell are being displayed full size in Firefox which is messing up my layout.

I was playing around with the inspector and I saw that if I untick display:table cell the layout goes back to how I want it.
Could I please have a pointer of how to override this in the CSS?

Comment: You can use any different `display` value. [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

Comment: @KittMedia thank you I used inline and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the `display` property depends on the specific element, but for layout elements it is most likely `block`. Therefore you can use `display:block` to reset the value to its cascading default.